# Check if file was uploaded or not

Tags: php, html

I am creating a social site. I have the option to upload up to 10 images with or without text, and the option to upload text without images.

So below I am trying to see if the user uploaded only text, or text with images. If the user uploaded only text then I want the text to be inserted into it's own separate table. If the user uploaded text with images or just images I want to check for that too. How can I check if the user uploaded images and if so run the images script and if not, jump out of the file ? This is what I have so far.

```
<input name="files[]" id='files' accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" type="file" multiple="multiple" />

$date_time = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
$img_limit = 10;
$maxsize = 4367463;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $errors = '';

    if ($_POST['title_post'] == '') {
        
        $errors = "Choose a topic.";

    } else {

        $create_topic = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO subtopic (subtopic, description) 
         VALUES (?, ?)");
        $create_topic->bind_param("ss", $_POST['title_post'], $_POST['description']);
        $create_topic->execute();
    }

    // --------------- CHECK IMAGES ----------****
    
    $file_count = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

    if ($file_count > 0) {

    if ($file_count > $img_limit) {
        $errors = 'Cannot upload more than 10 images';
    }

    if (!$errors) {

        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $file_path);

        // Loop through each file
        for( $i=0; $i < $file_count; $i++ ) {

            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            if ($file_size >= $maxsize) {

                $errors = "Your file is too large";

            } elseif ($imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "jpg" && 
                $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "gif") {

                $errors = "File type not allowed.";
            }
            //Make sure we have a file path
            if (!$errors /* && $file_tmp != "" */) {

                $picToUpload = $date_time . " -#- " . md5($file_name) . " -#- " . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                $uploadPicture = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "uploads/" . $picToUpload);

                $file_path = "uploads/" . $picToUpload;
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    }} else {

        header('Location: index4.php');
        exit();

    }
    // --------------- CHECK IMAGES ----------****
}
```

Comment: You can just check the $_FILES array, if it is empty you don't have any files.

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle I tried this and it didn't work `if(!file_exists($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])) {`

Comment: The file does not exist, since you are uploading multiple files. You should do if(!file_exists($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0])){} - where 0 = $i

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle wow thanks. Do you want to put it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the current file - for example:

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0])){

}
```

Where 0 is equal to $i